# Using CoolTerm to receive Serial Data into a saveable file

Tags: serial, sensors, datalogging, terminal

Have functional code that reads data from sensors. Found that I need to use a terminal program to grab the data from the serial output using CoolTerm by Roger Meier.

Wasn't able to test it with my code yet because of this issue: ([No Data Received on Serial Port & Unable to DFU Reset. Advice?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67401/no-data-received-on-serial-port-unable-to-dfu-reset-advice)).

Watched some videos and read some tutorials - does CoolTerm only come into play once I'm running the code? Can you write code for the arduino to automatically save stuff?

Comment: CoolTerm can save incoming data to a text file. In the help section, you can read about "Received data can be recorded to textfile using Connection/Capture to Textfile.", "Capture Text Options", "Leave File open while capturing" and "Add timestamps to received data".

Comment: VE7JRO - No, I get that CoolTerm can save data to a .txt file. But you have to open the CoolTerm GUI to do that right?

Comment: The CoolTerm app has to be running to capture data. Closing the app closes the serial connection and stops data logging. I un-checked the "Leave file open while capturing" check box under **options > receive** so I could open the text file and read it's contents while it's logging.

Comment: VE7JRO - Cool. Will do.